# Stretching a div vertically to fit content

Tags: html, css

How can I make the `.welcome-content-wrap` class stretch to fit its content and still keep the transparent style I've given it?

I understand that you wouldn't usually add background images like I have but there's a reason why I have done it like I have

```css
.welcome-section{
 position: relative;
}

.welcome-background{
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 height: auto;
}

.welcome-content-wrap{
 position: absolute;
 top:10%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 10%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 800px;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 text-align: center;
}

.welcome-content-wrap img{
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 margin: 50px auto;
}

.welcome-content-wrap p{
 color: #fff;
 margin: 25px;
}

.text-style{
 font-family: outstanding;
 font-size: 0.75em;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-section">
 <img class="welcome-background" src="images/menuBackground.jpg">
 <div class="welcome-content-wrap">
  <img src="images/welcomeTransparent.png">
 
  <p>
   <span class="text-style">WELCOME</span> to Popsie's of Bramhope a modern, local<br> 
   Yorkshire fish and chip shop. At Popsie's all our food is hand<br> prepared by Popsie's Dad in the shop's kitchen every day.
  </p>
  <p>All our fish is sourced from sustainable sources.</p>
  <p>
   We cook fish to order so that it isn't left to dry out under lights,<br> 
   like in too many chip shops.
  </p>
  <p>Our potatoes are from local Yorkshire & Lincolnshire farms and<br> we pride ourselves on using the best and freshest ingredients.</p>
 
  <img id="image-m" src="images/shutterstock_164403170.jpg">
  <img id="image-l" src="images/National-federation-of-fish-logo.png">
  <img id="image-r" src="images/CSSMSClogo.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you intended to do with that `absolute` positioning but I assume that you did *not* mean `horizontally` - as that was already covered - but `vertically` instead.

If I am right, this may be what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/tpfqk0v7/

What I changed is that `top:10%` and `bottom: 10%` and instead switched to `margins`

Sidenote: I just added the background to make it easier to see the actual changes. With everything being transparent and no background image to be seen it's a bit hard ;)

If you really meant the x-axis/horizontal wrapping, then of course just ignore my answer.

Comment: The original code has `max-width: 800px`. At view ports larger than that the element won't "stretch horizontally", so it's entirely possibly he *actually meant horizontally*. If you're unsure about the question or think the OP made a mistake you should comment on the question and ask for clarification rather than guessing in your answer. I am not saying you are incorrect, I am just suggesting getting clarification from the OP.

Comment: Thing is, one cannot comment before having 50 reputation, so how to ask?

Comment: If you can not comment and you are unsure about something in the question, then you should probably not submit a potentially low quality answer.

Comment: You're probably right and I will do that in the future. After a quick look on how the rendered html looked like I was pretty sure and now the question got updated and it is as it is.

Comment: Like I said in the first comment, I was not saying you were incorrect :)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `max-width: 800px` in the brackets for the `.welcome-content-wrap` class from your css file.

Answer (score 1):

width: 100%;

But you also have a max-width, you may want to check if that is preventing it.